# How to execute separate feature with cucumber and testng?

Tags: java, cucumber, testng

I try to execute cucumber tests, but my solution isn't working.
I had simplified the code to a very simple instance:

```java
public class FirstSteps extends TestRunner {

    @When("First Step")
    public void firstStep() {
        System.out.println("FirstSteps::firstStep");
    }

    @Then("Second Step")
    public void secondStep() {
        System.out.println("FirstSteps::secondStep");
    }
}

public class SecondSteps extends TestRunner {
    @When("First Function")
    public void firstFunction() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("SecondSteps::firstFunction ");
    }

    @Then("Second Function")
    public void secondFunction() {
        System.out.println("SecondSteps::secondFunction");
    }
}

@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources"})
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

smoke.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Test Debug">
    <test name="Test 1">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.projectname.tests.suites.FirstSteps"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

pom.xml:

```xml
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <!-- pass testng.xml files as argument from command line -->
                            ${suiteXmlFile}
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

- command to test execution:

`mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile="src/test/resources/suites/smoke.xml"`

**Expected result:**

> FirstSteps::firstStep
> FirstSteps::secondStep

**Actual result:**

> FirstSteps::firstStep
> FirstSteps::secondStep
> SecondSteps::firstFunction
> SecondSteps::secondFunction

---

As we can see the testing executes both classes: `FirstSteps` and `SecondSteps`, although I setup only `FirstSteps` in the `smoke.xml`

````
```
````

Comment: Remove `extends TestRunner ` and put all 3 classes in the same package. Use only `TestRunner` in your suite.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje But I need to execute different tests in my suite. If I will add TestRunner in the smoke.xml - which test (feature) will be executed?

Comment: The one you select with `features = {"...."}`. You can also put your feature selection in your xml suite. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-testng#configure-cucumber-options-via-testng-xml

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje
Thanks, obviously I saw this reference before but understood after your pointed me. This solution works well.